# javascript document.ready is replacing the whole content issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to create this `<div id="myid" >Hello Wordl!</div>` in the body of the page but my code problem is , after waiting 10 seconds it will replace this `<div id="myid" >Hello Wordl!</div>` with whole content of my page so it will only show this div.

here's my javascript code

```
 <script>
    setTimeout(function(){        
   $("body").prepend("<div id='myid'>hello world</div>");
},10000);
    },10000);
    </script>

and my page is like this

    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {margin:0;padding:0;}
    </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
    setTimeout(function(){        
    $("body").prepend("<div id='myid'>hello world</div>");
    },10000);
    </script>

    <!-- New div created by javascript must be here -->

    <div id="1">Keep This Div</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That javascript wont change the DOM at all, it just creates an object that you then do nothing with. Actually, a quick test and that code just throws and error about the tag name not being valid. Post code that actually replicates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){      

$("body").prepend("<div id='myid'>hello world</div>");
},10000);
</script>

<!-- New div created by javascript must be here -->

<div id="1">Keep This Div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is overwritten in your code. You try to create element (in wrong way) and do nothing with it.

```html
<div id="id1">Keep This Div</div>

<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = 'myid';
    el.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';

    document.getElementById('id1').prepend(el);
  }, 2000);
</script>
```

Note that `id="1"` is invalid value, I've changed it to `id1` in my example.

Comment: that id="1" or id1 has nothing to do with my pag or script, i just keep it in body in case for testing if javascript created a div and see if id="1" or id1 will stay steel or it will go away

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an element to your html body you can just create it and then append it like this:

```
var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
```

You can then add attributes and also innerHTML via Javascript like this:

```
elemDiv.id = 'myid';
elemDiv.innerHTML = 'Hello World!'
```